# How div automatically adjust their size and positions the element inside it

Tags: css

I am new to Css. I don't know whether this question had answer or not. Actually i have a page

```
<body>
    <div id="confirm">
        <img src="images/help.png" alt="Help Icon">
        <div id="message">
            Are you sure you want to  deletesadcasdsaduasudashdhasdoiasnidosanidoasyduiasnduasnoidnasidonasiodashydioasndoiasndioasdhioasydoiasndioashydasiodsaoidasd

        </div>

        <button>Ok</button>               
    </div>

</body>
```

I am setting his style. Here is my css

```
#confirm {

    background-color: #ddd;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    min-height:120px;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;              /*FireFox*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;           /*Opera, safari*/
    behavior: url(css/border-radius.htc);  /*IE*/
}

#confirm img {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:20px 20px 0 20px;
    float:left;
    width:64px;
}

#message {
    width: 280px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    white-space: normal;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#confirm button {
    position: relative;
    width:68px;
    margin:20px 180px 0 0;
    float:right;
}
```

Right now when i run my code it produses output like this

[image]

Now i want that no matter how large the text of the "message div" is. The "confirm div" automatically adjust their size and as well as positions all the elements inside it.
Like right now i have set "confirm div" "min-height = 120". As you see the text is cropping. The text should not be cropped, The size of message div should increase automatically depending on the size of text. As message div size increase, the confirm div also increase in height, confirm div adjust the image and button in it. Finally all the elements should be inside the confirm Div. Or you can say that the message and image should always be remain in the center of the div.
How can i do it?

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your message text has no white space and has a verrrry long word in it, you need to all that word to be broken to auto size the div

Add

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to the CSS for #messsage

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDqBZ/)

**Update**

Ok that proved difficult but does this work for you [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/gDqBZ/1/), I've added another div and put the image in that one, its positioned absolute not float so can centre the image.  Also had to add another div thats floated as the image was to force the message to be in the right place.

Comment: Thanks:) But i also want that the image should always be in the mid of my confirm Div. How can i do that? I mean to say, as my message Div is increasing, the image top should also move. Thanks

Comment: Perfect:) Awsome...Thanks:) But i want to  ask another thing..Does position matter in css. Like if i have a div, and i first define width, height property, then define border property and then define float property and so on. Then i shuffle the position. Now i define first transition property, then linear-gradient property, then border property, the width and height and so on. Does this thing makes any different in css. Actually i am asking this because i follow your trick but have properties defined on different places, centering didn't work, then i copy paste your trick and things are ok.

Comment: Also why the **#confirm img{} div** does not accept changes. Like in the #confirm imag div you set border. But when i change it to  `border:1px solid red;`. Then there is no red color. Also if i change the width from 64 to 100 `width:100px;`. Then there is no effect. Why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Also you set `margin-top: -32px;`. If i change it to 32 then it is not center. Why? 32 is half of height 64.

Comment: @Basit - your are right on the width:100px and the vertical-align not doing anything, sorry but I left them in while trying to get it to work.  the margin-top:-32px is as you rightly noticed, 1/2 of the height, this makes the top:50% and and margin together vertically center the fixed 64px high image. As for if the order of properties in a CSS block matter, I've done a quick search and it doesn't appear that it does.

Answer (score 1):

word-wrap: break-word; will serve the purpose.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tMVQ/)

**UPDATE**
[LIKE THIS middled from top?](http://jsfiddle.net/7tMVQ/3/)